# Just need help in python list value assignment

Tags: python, list

Refer following code

```
a1 = [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'T']]
print("a1 =",a1)
print("Making b1 copy of a1")
b1 = a1[:]
print("b1 = ",b1)
print("Changing one element of b1")
b1[1][1] = 'H'
print("b1 = ",b1)
print("a1 = ",a1)
```

this gives output as

```
a1 = [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'T']]
Making b1 copy of a1
b1 =  [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'T']]
Changing one element of b1
b1 =  [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'H']]
a1 =  [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'H']]
```

Why making changes to b1 changing a1 when i have created copy of a1 through slicing?

Comment: Because slicing is a _shallow_ copy.

Comment: You need to do a deep copy, try this, `import copy` then instead of `b1 = a1[:]`, do this, `b1 = copy.deepcopy(a1)`. There are also other ways to achieve this. It's because of how lists are stored in python, when you create a copy, only a pointer to the previous list is created. You are modifying the same object the pointers are pointing to. You need to create a proper copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because you don't create copy from nested list. You need nested copy:

```
b1 = [a[:] for a in a1]
# or
import copy
b1 = copy.deepcopy(a1)
```

Whole code:

```
# import copy
a1 = [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'T']]
print("a1 =",a1)
print("Making b1 copy of a1")
b1 = [a[:] for a in a1]
# b1 = copy.deepcopy(a1)
print("b1 = ",b1)
print("Changing one element of b1")
b1[1][1] = 'H'
print("b1 = ",b1)
print("a1 = ",a1)
```

Output:

```
a1 = [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'T']]
Making b1 copy of a1
b1 =  [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'T']]
Changing one element of b1
b1 =  [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'H']]
a1 =  [['H', 'T'], ['T', 'T']]
```

Comment: @RonDsouza, Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you [(see How to upvote on Stack Overflow?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing a list wont give you a hard or deep copy. If you want to copy a list see: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python

Comment: Please provide a summary of the answer in the link (with snippet, screenshot, etc.). The links are not always reliable.